# My Rpi can't connect again using Putty and VNC

Tags: vnc, connection, putty, picamera

I'm totally noobie in this area. I'm learning to use my RPi 3 model B. So at first I used it with my PC using tutorials in the web through Putty (SSH) and VNC viewer and everything worked fine. Then I tried latter when I bought my Pi Camera to use it again to config the camera but nothing seems to work.
What's going on?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you please describe in detail the problem you are having. "Nothing seems to work is a little vague for people to help"

Comment: I try to connect using Putty or the VNC viewer, but then the message "Network error: Connection timed out" appears. VNC the same.

Comment: What ip address the Raspi has? Can you ping it, e.g. `ping <ip address>`? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.